# How could I make picking the ascending and descending question error proof?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, binary-search

When I put a value that is not in the `if` statement in line 23, my code stops working. I want to know how to make that `if` portion of the code error proof. I know that this fix will involve a for loop, but I do not know where to start. I have the `if` loop telling the code that if the `order` equals 1, then search in an ascending (`expensesAscending`) order; if the `order` equals 2, then search in a descending (`expensedescending`) order.

```
package project;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int Size;//size of the array
        int order; // ascending or descending order
        int value;//this is for the value that you are looking for
        System.out.println("Put in the amount of expenses you have");
        Size = sc.nextInt();//User input for the amount of expenses
        System.out.println("put in all your expenses");
        int userInput[] = new int[Size];// what the users expenses are
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++)//This loop is for if the i value is smaller than user input then put in more values to complete the array
            userInput[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("do you want it ascending or descending order. If you want it in ascending press 1 or if you want descending press 2");
        order = sc.nextInt();// select if they wanted it in ascending or descending order
        System.out.print("expenses not sorted : ");
        printExpenses(userInput);//this is the method that prints out all the expenses
        if (order == 1) {
            expensesAscending(userInput);// If order is equal to one then sort in ascending else if it is equal to 2 then order it descending
        } else if (order == 2) {
            expensedescending(userInput);

        }
        System.out.println("what value are you looking for");
        value = sc.nextInt();
        if (order == 1) {int ans = binarySearchAscending(userInput, 0, Size-1, value);//use the binary search ascending method
        if(ans == -1)
            System.out.println("value not found");
          else
            System.out.println("your expense is found at "  + ans + " and the value of the array is " + userInput[ans]);
    }else if (order==2) {int ans = binarySearchDescending(userInput, 0, Size-1, value);//use the binary search descending method
    if(ans == -1)
        System.out.println("value not found");
      else
        System.out.println("your expense is found at " + ans + "and the value of the array is " + userInput[ans]);

    }}


    public static void printExpenses(int[] arr) {
        // this is were it is printed
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {//loops when i = to 0 and i is less than the length of the array then you should add one to the i value so that it could print out the entire array
            System.out.println(arr[i] + "$");
        }
    }

    public static void expensedescending(int arr[]) {
        // This is were the selection sort starts
        int N = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int small = arr[i];
            int pos = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
                if (arr[j] > small) {
                    small = arr[j];
                    pos = j;
                }
            }
            int temp = arr[pos];
            arr[pos] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
            System.out.println(": ");
            // Printing array after pass
            printExpenses(arr);
        }
    }

    public static void expensesAscending(int arr[]) {
        //insertion sort
        int N = arr.length;
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            int j = i - 1;
            int temp = arr[i];
            while (j >= 0 && temp < arr[j]) {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                j--;
                ;
            }
            arr[j + 1] = temp;
            System.out.println(": ");
            // Printing array after pass
            printExpenses(arr);
        }
    }
    static int binarySearchAscending(int[] array, int left, int right, int key) {
        if (left > right) {
          return -1;
        }

        int mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if (array[mid] == key) {
          return mid;
        }

        if (array[mid] > key) {
          return binarySearchAscending(array, left, mid - 1, key);
        }

        return binarySearchAscending(array, mid + 1, right, key);
      }


    static int binarySearchDescending(int[] array, int left, int right, int key) {
        if (left > right) {
          return -1;
        }

        int mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if (array[mid] == key) {
          return mid;
        }

        if (array[mid] > key) {
          return binarySearchDescending(array, mid + 1, right, key);
        }

        return binarySearchDescending(array, left, mid - 1, key);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get the `InputMismatchException` if you do `sc.nextInt()` and supply a non-integer (in your case, say some character).

In order to make this error proof, you will have to catch the exception with a `try-catch` block.

You can do something like this for the `sc.nextInt()` part.

```
try {
 order = sc.nextInt();
 //other lines
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
 // do required processing here
}
```

Now, this takes care of non integers. For checking if the numbers are just 1 and 2, you can utilize a while/do-while loop.

```
do {
try {
order = sc.nextInt();
//other lines
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
// do required processing here
}
} while (1 != order && 2 != order);
```

Comment: how would I add It to my code because when I add it I have the same issue in where it just stops and allows me to enter an infinite amount of user input

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that it's not error proof you are looking for. Error usually means an exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a do-while:

```
do {
    System.out.println("do you want it ascending or descending order. If you want it in ascending press 1 or if you want descending press 2");
    order = sc.nextInt();
} while (order != 1 && order != 2);
```